# Gremlin - How to return a property of an edge alongside a node result?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I would like to know how to add  to the result a property of the edge that links a node to another node

I'm using node.js to make queries to a Neptune database through Gremlin. Then I send the result to Javascript through an API.

```js
let data = [];
const id_vertex = "1"
data = await g.V().has(id,id_vertex)
        .out()

        .valueMap()

        .with_('~tinkerpop.valueMap.tokens'))

        .toList();
```

This is how data looks like:

```
[

  {

    name: [ 'Colt Bogan II' ],

    label: 'User',

    notification: [ 'Both' ],

    usercity: [ 'Wardburgh' ],

    id: '1',

    RegisteredDate: [ '2010-10-14' ]

  },

  {

    name: [ 'Webster Sanford' ],

    label: 'User',

    notification: [ 'SMS' ],

    usercity: [ 'Nanniefurt' ],

    id: '2',

    RegisteredDate: [ '2006-02-03' ]

  }

]
```

Then I use JSON.stringify to make the body of what I send back to javascript

```js
body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

```
"body": 
"[{\"name\":[\"Colt Bogan II\"],\"label\":\"User\",\"notification\":[\"Both\"],\"usercity\":[\"Wardburgh\"],\"id\":\"1\",\"RegisteredDate\":[\"2010-10-14\"]},
{\"name\":[\"Webster Sanford\"],\"label\":\"User\",\"notification\":[\"SMS\"],\"usercity\":[\"Nanniefurt\"],\"id\":\"2\",\"RegisteredDate\":[\"2006-02-03\"]}]"
```

I would like to add the property of the edge that connects my node that has the id id_vertex to another node (when returning all the properties of that node) in the body. Either while I'm making the Gremlin query or after that. Let's say that the edge property I'm interested in is color, then in the end the body I would like to look like this:

```
"body": 
"[{\"edgeColor\":[\"Green\"], \"name\":[\"Colt Bogan II\"],\"label\":\"User\",\"notification\":[\"Both\"],\"usercity\":[\"Wardburgh\"],\"id\":\"1\",\"RegisteredDate\":[\"2010-10-14\"]},
{\"edgeColor\":[\"Blue\"], \"name\":[\"Webster Sanford\"],\"label\":\"User\",\"notification\":[\"SMS\"],\"usercity\":[\"Nanniefurt\"],\"id\":\"2\",\"RegisteredDate\":[\"2006-02-03\"]}]"
```

Also, I have maximum one edge from one node to another, if this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your query slightly you can include edge properties in the result.

```
let data = [];
const id_vertex = "1"

data = await g.V().has(id,id_vertex)
        .outE()
        .project('edge','vertex')
           .by(valueMap('edgeColor'))
           .by(inV().valueMap().with_('~tinkerpop.valueMap.tokens'))
        .toList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If edgeColor was a value (like 10, 20) do you also know how I could return the result ordered in decreasing order?

Comment: nevermind, I now know how to do that

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I would appreciate you accepting the answer if it worked for you so others can see this is resolved. Many thanks.